# Python Flask as a Cloud Foundry app vs as a container

Tags: python, flask, containers, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm new to IBM Cloud and cloud platforms in general and wanted to start my Flask app on IBM Cloud, I just started with this [Getting started with Python](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/get-started-python/blob/master/README.md) but I'm very confused with how it will work.

- Is Cloud Foundry working the same way as containers work?
- How the platform handle the dependencies in order to Flask use them in both deployment ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is (almost) too broad. I can give you some basic answers, but everything else should be separate questions when you run into specific problems. You are referring to the [Getting Started with Python and Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/python/getting-started.html#getting_started) (this is the IBM Cloud docs, not the GitHub repo).

- When working with Cloud Foundry (CF), the CF environment and buildpack takes care of the dependencies. For Python, they are specified in the file **requirements.txt** and there is the file **manifest.yml** to configure the app, its name, memory usage, domain and more. When you push the app (either `cf push` or `ibmcloud cf push`) the two files are taken into account and everything else is done automatically. That's the appeal of Cloud Foundry.
- With containers, you would write a Dockerfile, then build the container image, push the image to a container registry, deploy the container to Kubernetes. When you build the container, your script would need to take care of resolving the dependencies (based on **requirements.txt**) and include the necessary modules into the image.

I recommend reading the [Deploy an Application](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html) Cloud Foundry doc as a starter to give some more background. There is also a simple [IBM Cloud solution tutorial that walks you through the steps of deploying a Flask app with a Db2 database](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/sql-database.html). That same site with [IBM Cloud solution tutorials](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/index.html) also has an overview of tutorials by deployment option (Cloud Foundry, Kubernetes, Cloud Functions, etc.).